# How can I fix the header and make the body and footer scrollable when window height is reduced?

Tags: html, css

I'm making myself a portfolio website and am having trouble with the body scrolling underneath the header and footer when the window height is reduced.

I believe the problem is with multiple parts of my CSS, the header and footer as well as possibly either the whole body or specific parts of it like the background image itself. Before the body started scrolling underneath the footer I was having problems with the footer not  going all the way to the bottom of the page and the background image sticking out from the bottom. Adjusting the footer p padding seemed to fix it but then this happened.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  background: url(Photo-by-Artem-Podrez-from-Pexels.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

p {
  margin-block-start: 0em;
  margin-block-end: 0em;
}

#header {
  background-color: #A97938;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

#name {
  color: #335067;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#self {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 95px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

div#nav-bar {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#name {
  max-height: 60px;
}

div#links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

div#links>a {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#about-me-text {
  display: block;
  color: #D4A66A;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #A97938;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.footer p {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="homepage_redo_style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha256-46qynGAkLSFpVbEBog43gvNhfr0j+BmwXdxFgVK/Kvc=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body id="home" class="vsc-initialized">
  <!-- nav bar -->
  <div id="header">
    <div id="nav-bar" class="container">
      <div id="name">My Name</div>
      <div id="links">
        <a href="projects_redo.html">Projects</a>
        <a href="resume (2).docx" target="_blank">Resume</a>
        <a href id="contact-link">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bg">
    <div class="about-me-wrapper">
      <img id="self" src="WIN_20210912_15_35_13_Pro.jpg" width="184" height="262">
      <p id="about-me-text">As someone with a physical disability, my daily life involves a lot of problem solving. This directly translates into my web development career as my disability gives me a unique perspective on how to get code to do what I want and in designing
        websites. I love learning new things and seeing the results of a job well done is very satisfying and fulfilling to me. I'm always looking for ways to gain experience and challenge myself, so if you have something I may be a good fit for feel
        free to send me an email.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="container footer">
      <div id="contact">
        <p class="align-center">Contact Info:</p>
        <p class="align-center">
          Email:
          <a href="mailto:my email address">my email address</a>
          <br> Phone:
          <a href="tel:my phone number">my phone number</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="social">
        <a href="linkedin profile link" target="_blank">
          <img src="linkedin-social.png" alt>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p class="align-center">© 2022 by My Name
          <br> All rights reserved.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="contact-modal" class="model" style="display: 
                block;">
    <div class="model-content">
      <h1>Contact Info:</h1>
      <br>
      <p>
        Feel free to contact me!
        <br> Email me at
        <a href="mailto:my email address">my email 
                            address</a>
        <br> or call at:
        <a href="tel:my phone number">my phone 
                            number</a>
        <br>
      </p>
      <img src="close_icon.jpg" alt class="model-close" id="close-contact-modal">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="homepage.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nest the content in a `wrapper` then use `overflow-y: scroll;` on that div.

I added a bunch more text so you can see the demonstration.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

html {
  background: url(Photo-by-Artem-Podrez-from-Pexels.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

p {
  margin-block-start: 0em;
  margin-block-end: 0em;
}


#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#header {
  background-color: #A97938;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

#name {
  color: #335067;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#self {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 95px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

div#nav-bar {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#name {
  max-height: 60px;
}

div#links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

div#links>a {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#about-me-text {
  display: block;
  color: #D4A66A;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #A97938;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.footer p {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="homepage_redo_style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha256-46qynGAkLSFpVbEBog43gvNhfr0j+BmwXdxFgVK/Kvc=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body id="home" class="vsc-initialized">
  <!-- nav bar -->
  <div id="header">
    <div id="nav-bar" class="container">
      <div id="name">Kyle Williams</div>
      <div id="links">
        <a href="projects_redo.html">Projects</a>
        <a href="resume (2).docx" target="_blank">Resume</a>
        <a href id="contact-link">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="bg">
    <div class="about-me-wrapper">
      <img id="self" src="WIN_20210912_15_35_13_Pro.jpg" width="184" height="262">
      <p id="about-me-text">As someone with a physical disability, my daily life involves a lot of problem solving. This directly translates into my web development career as my disability gives me a unique perspective on how to get code to do what I want and in designing
        websites. I love learning new things and seeing the results of a job well done is very satisfying and fulfilling to me. I'm always looking for ways to gain experience and challenge myself, so if you have something I may be a good fit for feel
        free to send me an email.</p>
        <p id="about-me-text">As someone with a physical disability, my daily life involves a lot of problem solving. This directly translates into my web development career as my disability gives me a unique perspective on how to get code to do what I want and in designing
        websites. I love learning new things and seeing the results of a job well done is very satisfying and fulfilling to me. I'm always looking for ways to gain experience and challenge myself, so if you have something I may be a good fit for feel
        free to send me an email.</p>
        <p id="about-me-text">As someone with a physical disability, my daily life involves a lot of problem solving. This directly translates into my web development career as my disability gives me a unique perspective on how to get code to do what I want and in designing
        websites. I love learning new things and seeing the results of a job well done is very satisfying and fulfilling to me. I'm always looking for ways to gain experience and challenge myself, so if you have something I may be a good fit for feel
        free to send me an email.</p>
        <p id="about-me-text">As someone with a physical disability, my daily life involves a lot of problem solving. This directly translates into my web development career as my disability gives me a unique perspective on how to get code to do what I want and in designing
        websites. I love learning new things and seeing the results of a job well done is very satisfying and fulfilling to me. I'm always looking for ways to gain experience and challenge myself, so if you have something I may be a good fit for feel
        free to send me an email.</p>
        <p id="about-me-text">As someone with a physical disability, my daily life involves a lot of problem solving. This directly translates into my web development career as my disability gives me a unique perspective on how to get code to do what I want and in designing
        websites. I love learning new things and seeing the results of a job well done is very satisfying and fulfilling to me. I'm always looking for ways to gain experience and challenge myself, so if you have something I may be a good fit for feel
        free to send me an email.</p>
        <p id="about-me-text">As someone with a physical disability, my daily life involves a lot of problem solving. This directly translates into my web development career as my disability gives me a unique perspective on how to get code to do what I want and in designing
        websites. I love learning new things and seeing the results of a job well done is very satisfying and fulfilling to me. I'm always looking for ways to gain experience and challenge myself, so if you have something I may be a good fit for feel
        free to send me an email.</p><p id="about-me-text">As someone with a physical disability, my daily life involves a lot of problem solving. This directly translates into my web development career as my disability gives me a unique perspective on how to get code to do what I want and in designing
        websites. I love learning new things and seeing the results of a job well done is very satisfying and fulfilling to me. I'm always looking for ways to gain experience and challenge myself, so if you have something I may be a good fit for feel
        free to send me an email.</p>
        <p id="about-me-text">As someone with a physical disability, my daily life involves a lot of problem solving. This directly translates into my web development career as my disability gives me a unique perspective on how to get code to do what I want and in designing
        websites. I love learning new things and seeing the results of a job well done is very satisfying and fulfilling to me. I'm always looking for ways to gain experience and challenge myself, so if you have something I may be a good fit for feel
        free to send me an email.</p><p id="about-me-text">As someone with a physical disability, my daily life involves a lot of problem solving. This directly translates into my web development career as my disability gives me a unique perspective on how to get code to do what I want and in designing
        websites. I love learning new things and seeing the results of a job well done is very satisfying and fulfilling to me. I'm always looking for ways to gain experience and challenge myself, so if you have something I may be a good fit for feel
        free to send me an email.</p>
        <p id="about-me-text">As someone with a physical disability, my daily life involves a lot of problem solving. This directly translates into my web development career as my disability gives me a unique perspective on how to get code to do what I want and in designing
        websites. I love learning new things and seeing the results of a job well done is very satisfying and fulfilling to me. I'm always looking for ways to gain experience and challenge myself, so if you have something I may be a good fit for feel
        free to send me an email.</p>
        <p id="about-me-text">As someone with a physical disability, my daily life involves a lot of problem solving. This directly translates into my web development career as my disability gives me a unique perspective on how to get code to do what I want and in designing
        websites. I love learning new things and seeing the results of a job well done is very satisfying and fulfilling to me. I'm always looking for ways to gain experience and challenge myself, so if you have something I may be a good fit for feel
        free to send me an email.</p>
        <p id="about-me-text">As someone with a physical disability, my daily life involves a lot of problem solving. This directly translates into my web development career as my disability gives me a unique perspective on how to get code to do what I want and in designing
        websites. I love learning new things and seeing the results of a job well done is very satisfying and fulfilling to me. I'm always looking for ways to gain experience and challenge myself, so if you have something I may be a good fit for feel
        free to send me an email.</p>
        <p id="about-me-text">As someone with a physical disability, my daily life involves a lot of problem solving. This directly translates into my web development career as my disability gives me a unique perspective on how to get code to do what I want and in designing
        websites. I love learning new things and seeing the results of a job well done is very satisfying and fulfilling to me. I'm always looking for ways to gain experience and challenge myself, so if you have something I may be a good fit for feel
        free to send me an email.</p>
        <p id="about-me-text">As someone with a physical disability, my daily life involves a lot of problem solving. This directly translates into my web development career as my disability gives me a unique perspective on how to get code to do what I want and in designing
        websites. I love learning new things and seeing the results of a job well done is very satisfying and fulfilling to me. I'm always looking for ways to gain experience and challenge myself, so if you have something I may be a good fit for feel
        free to send me an email.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="container footer">
      <div id="contact">
        <p class="align-center">Contact Info:</p>
        <p class="align-center">
          Email:
          <a href="mailto:kyle.williams521997@gmail.com">kyle.williams521997@gmail.com</a>
          <br> Phone:
          <a href="tel:2168152705">(216) 815-2705</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="social">
        <a href="linkedin.com/in/kyle-williams-b5bb60162" target="_blank">
          <img src="linkedin-social.png" alt>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p class="align-center">© 2022 by Kyle Williams
          <br> All rights reserved.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="contact-modal" class="model" style="display: block;">
    <div class="model-content">
      <h1>Contact Info:</h1>
      <br>
      <p>
        Feel free to contact me!
        <br> Email me at
        <a href="mailto:kyle.williams521997@gmail.com">kyle.williams521997@gmail.com</a>
        <br> or call at:
        <a href="tel:2168152705">(216) 815-2705</a>
        <br>
      </p>
      <img src="close_icon.jpg" alt class="model-close" id="close-contact-modal">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="homepage.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get it to scroll without adding extra text? Without the extra text the image I'm using and text paragraph just get stuck behind the footer.

Comment: What would be the point of the scroll if there’s no content for it? You should upload your images here: https://imgbb.com/ or on the stack servers so I can see what you’re talking about.